# Javascript object strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html

I executed this javascript code:

```
var motorbike = {
    "Wheel" : move(),
    "Motor" : start()
}; // CREATE MOTORBIKE OBJECT

document.write(motorbike.Wheel); // MOVE MY MOTORBIKE
document.write(motorbike.Motor); // START MY MOTORBIKE

function move(){
    return "-I'm moving<br/>";
}

function start(){
    document.write("-Starting<br/>");
   return "-Broom broom...";
}
```

In the screen should appear:

```
-I'm moving
-Starting
-Broom broom...
```

But when I execute it...

```
-Starting
-I'm moving
-Broom broom...
```

Javascript prints first the "direct" document.write (that which has a string directly written) and then prints the ones which work with a return. Why javascript does that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at :

```
var motorbike = {
    "Wheel" : move(),
    "Motor" : start()
};
```

Those methods run  , not when you call the property but when the object is built !

This is why the `document.write` of `start`  is invoked and hence you see the string from : `document.write("-Starting<br/>");` first.

Try run this :

```
var motorbike = {
    "Wheel" : alert('1')
};
```

You will immediately see the alert immediately !

You're *probably* after :

```
var motorbike = {
    "Wheel" : move,
    "Motor" : start
}; // CREATE MOTORBIKE OBJECT

document.write(motorbike.Wheel()); // MOVE MY MOTORBIKE
document.write(motorbike.Motor()); // START MY MOTORBIKE
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
var motorbike = {
    "Wheel" : move(),
    "Motor" : start()
};
```

the `start` function is executed, and `-Starting` printed.

`-I'm moving` and `-Broom broom...` are printed after because the `document.write()` function is called after the `motorbike` object declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the functionality to the object, you have to assign the name only, without the parenthesis:

```
var motorbike = {
    "Wheel" : move,
    "Motor" : start
};
```

If you say `Wheel: move()` , move is executed immediately and the result is assigned to the property Wheel. Therefore `move` and `start` are both executed during initalization, and start writes starting. The *results* (as in the strings returned by the function) are written thereafter when writing `document.write(motorbike.Wheel);` and `document.write(motorbike.Motor);`

PS If the functions are assigned, when using them afterwards, you do need the parenthesis, to call the function : `document.write(motorbike.Wheel());`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript executes your code from top to down.

So the function `move()` gets executed and returns `-I'm moving<br/>` which gets set as value of Wheel. Then `start()` gets executed and it immediately writes `-Starting<br/>` to the `document`. After that the lines

```
document.write(motorbike.Wheel); // MOVE MY MOTORBIKE
document.write(motorbike.Motor); // START MY MOTORBIKE
```

are executed and append the value of `Wheel` and `Moter` to the document.

If your `start()` would return the whole text, it would work as you expect.

```
function start(){
   return "-Starting<br/>-Broom broom...";
}
```